# Unable to install Ubuntu on hp dv6-7003tx

Tags: system-installation

I have been trying to install Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS on my hp dv6-7003tx.

I recently formatted the laptop and tried to install Ubuntu on it without installing Windows 7, but failed.

The problem I'm having right now is as follows.

1. I select 'install Ubuntu'
2. Before entering GUI for installation error message pops up as follows,

   [image: Installation error message]
3. Then, during the 4th installation process(Installation type), I can't see any root directory, i.e. it's empty.
4. When I click 'install now', it says 'No root file system is defined'.

Here's what I've done.

1. Install Windows 7 first.
2. Install drivers.
3. Divide local hard drive into two partitions (in exFAT)

Nothing has worked so far.

What should I do to install Ubuntu into my laptop?

Answer (score 2):

Since you already have Win-7 installed and have dedicated a proper partition for Ubuntu, simply follow the steps given below:

- While installation, choosing *Install alongside Windows boot manager* is safe, but please do take note of everything to avoid messing your hard disk. If you are in any doubt, stick with *Something Else* option only.
- Take help of the [dual boot Windows and Linux](https://www.tecmint.com/install-ubuntu-16-04-alongside-with-windows-10-or-8-in-dual-boot/) link to properly perform the installation process in a step-wise manner.

P.S - Do create `Swap` partition as well. It won't impact your working in any way possible.

Once you have installed Ubuntu (following the above link properly), start with the process of setting up the grub menu:

- Boot into `Windows` OS
- Combine <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>r</kbd> keys together and type `cmd` to open command prompt
- Type `bcdedit /set "{bootmgr}" path \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi` and hit the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key

P.S - No admin right is required to perform the above-said operation.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to run ubuntu from the installation media first to see if it can recognize the partition.

Outside of that i would suggest using wubi.exe while running windows to install from there.